# SoapUI Mock Response - Script returned null

Tags: mocking, response, soapui

Please could someone advise with the blow query.

I have set up a Mock Response, which successfully responds to the incoming request. I am trying to extract certain details from the inbound request using the 'SCRIPT' dispatch method.

I have added the following line, but when I execute it returns 'Script returned [null]'

def holder = new com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder( mockRequest.requestContent )

Am I missing something as I can see the request arriving in the 'Request' window.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context) 
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("mockRequest#Request")
```

where mockRequest is the name of your request,

you could change mockRequest#Request with mockRequest#Response if you want response to be picked up as XML

Additionally for picking any value from the XML you can use below

```
  def value= holder.getNodeValue( '//*:tagname/*:tagname1' )
```

This will get you the value from the response

Answer (score 0):

When I used XmlHolder to parse a SoapUI response, I used different property on the response to feed XmlHolder.

E.g.

```
holder = new XmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContentAsXml );
```

Following this, you may have to define some of the namespaces before extracting the values of interest.

The below is purely a pseudo example to try and help you get moving...

```
holder.namespaces["ns1"] = "urn:someOrg:app:userDetails:domain:1";

def userId = holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:userDetailsArray[1]/ns1:user[1]/ns1:id[1]");
def userName = holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:userDetailsArray[1]/ns1:user[1]/ns1:name[1]");
```